# Problems with property editor in Embarcadero XE6

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe6

As usual, every new release of c++ builder takes days of changes...
I'm having trouble fixing a property editor, the code is:

********************* THE H FILE ********************************

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef ufrmLabelEditorH
#define ufrmLabelEditorH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Buttons.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>

#include <DesignIntf.hpp>
#include <TypInfo.hpp>
#include <DesignEditors.hpp>
#include <Classes.hpp>

// Add DesignIDE.bpi to your package's Requires list in the Project Manager
#pragma comment(lib, "DesignIDE.bpi")



//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


class TfrmLabelEditor : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
TPanel *Panel1;
TMemo *Memo1;
TBitBtn *BitBtn1;
TBitBtn *BitBtn2;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
__fastcall TfrmLabelEditor(TComponent* Owner);
};


class PACKAGE TLabelProperty : public TStringProperty
{
public:
virtual Designintf::TPropertyAttributes __fastcall GetAttributes() {
    return TStringProperty::GetAttributes()<<paDialog;
}

virtual void __fastcall Edit(void) {
    TfrmLabelEditor *frmEditor = new TfrmLabelEditor(Application);
    frmEditor->Memo1->Lines->Text = GetStrValue();
    try {
        if (frmEditor->ShowModal()==mrOk) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < PropCount; i++) {
                ((TLabel*)GetComponent(i))->Caption = frmEditor->Memo1->Lines->Text;
            }
            Modified();
        }
    } catch (...) {
    }
    frmEditor->Free();
}

};



//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TfrmLabelEditor *frmLabelEditor;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

****************** THE CPP FILE *****************************

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "ufrmLabelEditor.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TfrmLabelEditor *frmLabelEditor;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TfrmLabelEditor::TfrmLabelEditor(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Labelproperty {

void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
{
    TTypeInfo* typeInfo = new TTypeInfo();
    typeInfo->Name = "AnsiString";
    typeInfo->Kind = tkLString;

    Designintf::RegisterPropertyEditor(typeInfo,__classid(TfrmLabelEditor),"Caption",     __classid(TLabelProperty));

    TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TfrmLabelEditor)};
    RegisterComponents(L"SGM", classes, 0);
}
}
```

Both files are part of a design time only c++ package....

Any help? If not, please tell me about some c++ ide that realy works!!!!! THANKS.....

Comment: and the problem is...?

Comment: Why are you registering a property editor for a property of a design-time editor? You should be registering it for a property of a runtime component instead. Where is your component?

Comment: Matt: The problem is that nothing occurs, the code runs without errors, the package is installed ok, but no editor for captions... only that, typical for Embarcadero....

Comment: Remy: I don´t understand your question, the editor is made for caption properties of TLabel and other components.

Comment: About sugestions for another IDE, I'm not joking, I'm very tired of this life of struggle with Embarcadero. If someone has a hint of some other IDE I will be gratefull!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Register()` function relies on an unnecessary hack to fake `AnsiString` RTTI.  Not only that, but the VCL uses Unicode strings in XE6, so unless your `Caption` property is actually declared as `AnsiString` then your property editor will not register correctly.

Let the property itself provide the correct RTTI to you.  The [RegisterPropertyEditor() documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) even demonstrates this.  This approach works in every version of C++Builder (and Delphi):

```
void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
{
    PPropInfo pProp = GetPropInfo(__typeinfo(TfrmLabelEditor), "Caption");
    RegisterPropertyEditor(*(pProp->PropType), __classid(TfrmLabelEditor), "Caption", __classid(TLabelProperty));

    TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TfrmLabelEditor)};
    RegisterComponents(L"SGM", classes, 0);
}
```

**Update**: That being said, this registration will never work, because you are setting the second parameter of `RegisterPropertyEditor()` to the wrong value.

`TfrmLabelEditor` is itself implemented and exists only in a design-time package. By setting the second parameter to `TfrmLabelEditor`, the Object Inspector will invoke `TLabelProperty` only when an instance of `TfrmLabelEditor` is active in the Form Designer and its `Caption` property is edited in the Object Inspector.  But the Form Designer will never see instances of `TfrmLabelEditor` in projects, so the Object Inspector will never invoke your `TLabelProperty` editor.  That is why you don't see anything happen.

[Read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) more carefully.  The second parameter specifies a specific **runtime** component type, or `NULL` for all component types, that have the specified property of the specified property type.  `TfrmLabelEditor` does not qualify for that.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your comments, i have tried your exact code but still not working! No errors, compile ok, add package ok but still no editor...

Comment: It does not work because you are setting the second parameter of `RegisterPropertyEditor()` to the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

A little adaptation of REMY SOLUTION have worked, not sure why:

```
void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
{
    TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TfrmLabelEditor)};

    //********* register my editors ******************
    PPropInfo PropInfo = GetPropInfo(__typeinfo(TForm), "Caption");
    Designintf::RegisterPropertyEditor(*(PropInfo->PropType),NULL,"Caption", __classid(TLabelProperty));
    //*************************************************

    RegisterComponents(L"SGM", classes, 0);
}
```

Comment: It "works" because you are retrieving the native `String` RTTI from a known runtime component, and then setting the second parameter of `RegisterPropertyEditor()` to NULL, so you are essentially saying "Register TLabelProperty for the Caption property of all components where Caption is a String".  Your original code said "Register TLabelProperty for the Caption property of TfrmLabelEditor where Caption is an AnsiString" instead, which will not work.